# VBA function - use range as criteria

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a VBA function that looks up certain number ID to decide what percentage to use.

I want to make it more dynamic and have a range where the user can enter the ID's so I don't have to manually change it and its static. As you can see in the function onshore.

```
Function ownershipOffshore(TaxLot)
  If TaxLot = 0 Then
    ownershipOffshore = 0#
  ElseIf TaxLot = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("K26").Value Then
    ownershipOffshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("E4").Value
    ' 51506431 Or TaxLot = 51533686 Or TaxLot = 51533687 Or TaxLot = 51533688 Or TaxLot = 51533689 Or TaxLot = 51706542 Or TaxLot = 51864049 Or TaxLot = 51953620 Or TaxLot = 51981353 Or TaxLot = 52142917 Or TaxLot = 52142919 Or TaxLot = 52142920
  ElseIf TaxLot = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("K11:K22").Value Then
    ownershipOffshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("E3").Value
  Else
    ownershipOffshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("E2").Value
  End If
End Function

Function ownershipOnshore(TaxLot)
  If TaxLot = 0 Then
    ownershipOnshore = 0#
  ElseIf TaxLot = 70376132 Then
    ownershipOnshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("K26").Value
  ElseIf TaxLot = 51506431 Or TaxLot = 51533686 Or TaxLot = 51533687 Or TaxLot = 51533688 Or TaxLot = 51533689 Or TaxLot = 51706542 Or TaxLot = 51864049 Or TaxLot = 51953620 Or TaxLot = 51981353 Or TaxLot = 52142917 Or TaxLot = 52142919 Or TaxLot = 52142920 Or TaxLot = 70376132 Then
    ownershipOnshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("F3").Value
  Else
    ownershipOnshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("F2").Value
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Your function can take inputs byval or byref. Check those things out.

Answer (score 0):

You can take in a range as a parameter to a function. You can find [an example of passing a range into a UDF on my blog](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/excel-sqlconcat-function-revisited/).

In your case, you would want to replace this Elif

> ```
>  ElseIf TaxLot = 51506431 Or TaxLot = 51533686 Or TaxLot = 51533687 Or TaxLot = 51533688 Or TaxLot = 51533689 Or TaxLot =
> 51706542 Or TaxLot = 51864049 Or TaxLot = 51953620 Or TaxLot =
> 51981353 Or TaxLot = 52142917 Or TaxLot = 52142919 Or TaxLot =
> 52142920 Or TaxLot = 70376132 Then
>
> ownershipOnshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("F3").Value
>
>  Else
> ```

With a boolean function.

```
 Private Function IsTaxLotInUserRange(byval rng Range, TaxLot)
     Dim cell as Range
     For Each cell in rng
         If TaxLot = cell.Value Then
             IsTaxLotInUserRange = True
             Exit Function
         End If
     Next
End Function
```

And update your elif with

```
ElseIf IsTaxLotInRange(rng, TaxLot) Then
    ownershipOnshor = ownershipOnshore = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("F3").Value
Else
```

Comment: Great idea, thank for sharing it with me. Maybe I did something wrong,  so got value error . Thus I tried to give the vba function a range where it nees to look where the constant ID are sitting for it to compare, before I hard coded the Ids into theVBA , as you saw. But still get the Value error. My question is how does the function know where the range is if the originaal function has only one input variable, the tax lot and it needs to check the taxlot against a range, like a vlookup
 rng = Sheets("Ownership %").Range("K11:K22").Value